# Augmenting AVL tree to calculate sum of subtree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, avl-trees

Suggest a way to augment an AVL tree to support a $O(\log n)$ implementation of the function
`calculateSum(key)`, which receives a key of a node and returns the sum of its subtree.

I implemented it this way:

```
sumSubtree(node):
    if node != null:
        return sumSubtree(node.left) + sumSubtree(node.right) + node.key
    return 0
    
calculateSum(key):
    node = Search(key) // assuming I have a search function
    return sumSubtree(node)
```

which solves it in $O(\log n)$.

But I read it is possible to maintain the sum during insertion and deletion. And augment an AVL tree this way.

Which solution would be better? Mine, or the other method? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is traversing the whole subtree on each call to `subSubtree` so it is actually $O(|T|) \neq O(\log n)$ where $|T|$ is the length of the subtree. If I query the root of the tree it will go over every node, so complexity is $O(n)$.

If you keep the sum of the subtree while modifying it (insertions/deletions) then the pseudo-code will look like:

```
calculateSum(key):
    node = Search(key) // assuming I have a search function in O(log n)
    return node->size
```

Search can be implemented in $O(\log n)$ and getting the size is $O(1)$ since it is stored on the node itself, hence the overall complexity will be $O(\log n)$.